# How can I use QSettings to write UTF-8 characters into [section] and [name] of *.ini file properly?

Tags: qt, encoding, utf-8, ini, qsettings

My code snippet is here:

```
QSettings setting("xxx.ini", QSettings::Format::IniFormat);
setting.setIniCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
setting.beginGroup(u8"运动控制器");
setting.setValue(u8"运动控制器", u8"运动控制器");
setting.endGroup();
```

But what is written looks like this:

```
[%U8FD0%U52A8%U63A7%U5236%U5668]
%U8FD0%U52A8%U63A7%U5236%U5668=运动控制器
```

So it seems I did set the encoding correctly (partly), but what should I do to change the section and name into text from some per-cent-sign code?

Environment is Qt 5.12.11 and Visual Studio 2019

Comment: how are you verifying that result? maybe is an issue in the editor you are using....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツbecause the output is partly ok and partly not, shouldn't be editor's problem

Comment: Maybe this is Qt specific. It writes tags, keys as Unicode hex values and the rest as Unicode literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is *hard-coded behavior* in `QSettings` that you simply cannot change.

In section and key names, Unicode characters <= U+00FF (other than `a..z`, `A..Z`, `0..9`, `_`, `-`, or `.`) are encoded in `%XX` hex format, and higher characters are encoded in `%UXXXX` format.  The codec specified in `setIniCodec()` has no effect on this behavior.

Key values are written in the specified codec, in this case UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But does that just means I have no way to write some specific characters into ini sections and key names using QSettings?

Comment: @QingguoHu you can use whatever characters you want, but they simply won't be formatted the way you want. If you want the file to appear a specific way, you should write the file yourself.